# RealityKit: change the scale of a ModelEntity without changing its position

Tags: animation, augmented-reality, realitykit, ios-animations

I have an ModelEntity animation that move from point A to point B and takes a while to complete. When the user taps on the ModelEntity I would like to add a shrinking animation to the ModelEntity as well.

I tried adding the scale animation directly to the ModelEntity view .move but the problem there is I current transform of the model is where the model is expected to end. Causing the ModelEnity to jump to the end of the animation.

```
var transform = modelEntity.transform 
transform.scale *= factor
modelEntity.move(to: transform, relativeTo: modelEntity.parent, duration: duration) // will not work because the translation of the transform is already at the end of the animation
```

Is there a way to add a scaling animation to ModelEntity that is already in the middle of a different animation and make them work together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested with Xcode 14.2. :

```
import RealityKit
import CoreGraphics

extension Entity {
    
    func scaleAnimated(with value: SIMD3<Float>, duration: CGFloat) {
        
        var scaleTransform: Transform = Transform()
        scaleTransform.scale = value
        self.move(to: self.transform, relativeTo: self.parent)
        self.move(to: scaleTransform, relativeTo: self.parent, duration: duration)
        
    }
    
}
```

Usage:

```
var scaleTransform: Transform = Transform()
        
if exampleEntity.scale.x == 1.0 {
   exampleEntity.scaleAnimated(with: [0.012, 0.012, 0.012], duration: 1.0)
} else {
    exampleEntity.scaleAnimated(with: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], duration: 1.0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example with an extension. Definitely the way to go.

Comment: Working with an immersive space in visionOS, I had to add scaleTransform.translation = self.position so that my entity did not move to the origin.

Answer (score 1):

This was a solution to my problem:

```
var transform = modelEntity.transform 
transform.scale *= factor
modelEntity.move(to: modelEntity.transform, relativeTo: modelEntity.parent)
modelEntity.move(to: transform, relativeTo: modelEntity.parent, duration: duration)
```

It looks like the problem was that I needed to get the entity to the position it was in at the middle of the animation. For some reason when you call the `.move` method it expects to start where it should have ended up regardless of the duration.